# 2D platformer PC game with time travel, portals and Ben 10-like animation

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I need the name of a 2D platformer PC video game which was probably released between 2000-2010.

The main characters are a teenage boy and a girl which I am sure of.

It's an action/adventure themed game that has some time travel elements in it like portals and such, the target audience would be kids/teenagers (zero nudity and less violence)

The game's look is a bit similar to Ubisoft's *Rayman* and has animation that's similar to the cartoon *Ben 10*.

The game is an international release and i'm thinking it might be an offline PC game.
Me and my brother used to play this in a normal computer at an internet cafe 10-12 years back.

It's not in the lists given in comments but thanks for sharing. The game I played isn't entirely time portal related, it has some creatures as villains (probably aliens). It's an adventure platform PC game but with good graphics like *Rayman*. It's definitely before the year 2008 that and definitely not a 8 or 16-bit game of which I am sure of.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but while I can't name one right away, "2D platformer with portals" seems a bit broad. Please take a look at [this guide on story-identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), as well as [this one on videogames](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11996/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. Anything making it more "unique" could be of help :)

Comment: Edited a bit, will add if I recall any additional details.

Comment: Another thing that might help narrow it down a bit: Were the time travel/portals an actual element of gameplay (you manipulate time like the game Braid to solve puzzles or portals like Portal) or more style and backstory (the portals and time travel were the excuse to go to various different levels, e.g., you might start in a future level and at the end cross a portal and are in a pirate level)

Comment: No manipulation, the portals were just to go to different places in the same level. I played like 50% of the game and haven't observed any bonus levels. Most of the backgrounds were similar to forest themes. No cities as far as I remember.

Comment: Was this installed, or via a website?

Comment: Installed, we used to open this by clicking the shortcut icon on the desktop right beside spider Man 2 pc game icon. I'm not sure if this game used internet while playing.

Comment: Any updates guys?

Comment: @Nithin nothing here so far, I probably can't think of the right set of keywords to Google. Don't worry though, sometimes story-id get answered way after, by people who instantly recognized the thing... Keep an eye on that thread and don't hesitate to edit any new info you could think of :) (also, you can reply to earlier comments by adding an at, `@Jenayah any update...`; this will send an inbox notification to the user you're @ing)

Comment: I [searched Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=deepcat%3A%22Video+games+about+time+travel%22+deepcat%3A%22Platform+games%22+deepcat%3A%22Video+games+featuring+female+protagonists%22&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22deepcategory%22%3A%5B%22Video+games+about+time+travel%22%2C%22Platform+games%22%2C%22Video+games+featuring+female+protagonists%22%5D%7D%2C%22namespaces%22%3A%5B0%5D%7D&ns0=1) for pages with [Video games about time travel], [Platform games], & [Video games featuring female protagonists], but no luck

Comment: There was a game which the theme was something like time travel that had a series of book with it, or the first book came with the game. I am almost positive one of the catchphrases was that the traveling took "an eternity and half"

Comment: Is the game on this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_containing_time_travel or somewhere on this tv-tropes page: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TimeTravel/VideoGames ?